# Javascript that can on multiple buttons dynamically generated from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-confirm

I have a javascript that creates a modal popup with [jquery-confirm](http://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/). It works on a single instance, but when there are multiple instances with the same  onClick events classname they all trigger at once. The idea is a list of videos to delete with a confirmation button.

How can I have one script address dynamic list with unique class names? [i.e] class="video1" class="video2" or using ID or something else so that the confirmation code only triggers uniquely?

**PHP and HTML** (for example this could generate ten of the HTML line below):

```
$stuff = mysql_query(
         "SELECT * FROM videolist where user_id = '$id' ORDER BY creation_date DESC"
         );
while ($ratch = mysql_fetch_array($stuff)) {
    $video_id= $ratch["id"];
    $title= $ratch["title"];
?>
<a class="delete" href="delete.php?d=<? echo $video_id; ?>">
   DELETE VIDEO!
</a>
<?   } ?>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**:

```
$('a.delete').confirm({
  buttons: {
   confirm: function () {location.href = this.$target.attr('href');},
   close: function () {}
  }
});
```

Comment: show a working example that demonstrates the problem (the code you provided should work as expected).

Answer (score 3):

First: I would put an id-attribute in the a-tags

```
<a class="delete" id="v1"></a>
<a class="delete" id="v2"></a>
<a class="delete" id="v3"></a>
```

Second: I would make an on click this id event

```
$('.delete').click({
 alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Third: send the id to the delete-script

Comment: HI @Bernhard tried this , but I still get multiple dialog boxes the same number of HTML entries with class=delete , as though i clicked on all of them at once

Comment: the id attribute should be named data-id get retrieved with $(this).data('id');

Comment: @Fight Fire With Fire I think you do something wrong then. Have you tried only my script?